# Category isn't getting related video blogs?

Tags: php, activerecord, relationship, phalcon

I am trying to get category related video blogs by below code but i get nothing in **var_dump**? I want to get category related videos:

```
 $category = VideoBlogCategoryModel::findFirst(1); // This returns category successfully and there are many video   blogs having this category linked
    var_dump($category->getVideoBlogs());exit;
```

**VideoBlogModel.php**

```
public function initialize(){

    // Run base initialize code
    parent::initialize();

    // Configure Relation with VideoBlogCategoryModel
    $this->belongsTo('category_id', VideoBlogCategoryModel::class, 'id', array(
        'alias' => 'videoCategory',
        'foreignKey' => true
    ));
}
public function getVideoCategory(){
    return $this->videoCategory;
}

public function setVideoCategory($videoCategory){
    $this->videoCategory = $videoCategory;
}
```

**VideoBlogCategoryModel.php**

```
public function initialize(){

    // Run base initialize code
    parent::initialize();

    // Configure relation with VideoBlogModel
    $this->hasMany('id', VideoBlogModel::class, 'category_id', array(
        'alias' => 'videoBlogs',
        'foreignKey' => true,
        'cxAction' => static::ACTION_CASCADE_DELETE
    ));
}
   public function getVideoBlogs(){
    return $this->videoBlogs;
}

public function setVideoBlogs($videoBlogs){
    $this->videoBlogs = $videoBlogs;
}
```

Let me know if anything else is required, I will share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `VideoBlogCategoryModel.php` change

```
public function getVideoBlogs() {
   return $this->videoBlogs;
}
```

to

```
public function getVideoBlogs() {
   return $this->getRelated('videoBlogs');
}
```

Then try accessing it like:

```
$category = VideoBlogCategoryModel::findFirst(1); 
$videos = $category->getVideoBlogs();

foreach( $videos as $video ) { 
  // access data here
  var_dump($video->anyProperty()); // e.g $video->getId()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try it

```
$category = VideoBlogCategoryModel::findFirst(1);
$videos = $category->getVideoBlogs();
var_dump($videos->count());
var_dump($videos->toArray());
exit;
```

I think use `var_dump` for a Phalcon Collection Object is not a good idea, you can convert it to Array and Var_dump

Hope it can help you

Comment: count and to array both function are throwing error i.e. 
count on NULL!

Answer (score 0):

Or try:

```
$categories = VideoBlogCategoryModel::findById($id);
```

Comment: Then what's the benefit of relationships
?

Comment: When you need to find cross-table data instead of writing manually joins. But without a parameter, how to look for records with certain criteria?